# How to change a orientation on button click like youTube app?

Tags: cocoa-touch, orientation

How can I change the orientation like youTube app.

[image]

When I click this button if view is in portrait mode it's rotate in a landscape mode or if view is in landscape mode it's rotate in a portrait mode and when I change orientation it also work.

Comment: change orientation of UIView portrait and landscape..

Answer (score 4):

try this 
first import this : 
 **`#import <objc/message.h>`**

Than is your button method use this

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)])
{

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice],@selector(setOrientation:),UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft );
    }else
    {
        objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientation);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the interface of the Youtube does not really rotate, they just present the video layer full screen and rotate the layer.

The same think happens when you rotate the device, they make the video layer fill the screen and rotate it according to the device rotation. Facebook does the same when viewing photo fullscreen and rotating the device just rotates the view.

You can start monitoring the rotation by asking `UIDevice` to generate device notation orientation notifications:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
   name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
   object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

Then in the `-(void)orientationChanged:` method change the UI:

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
   UIDevice * device = note.object;

   CGAffineTransform transfrom;
   CGRect frame = self.videoView.frame;   

   switch(device.orientation)
   {
       case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
       case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:       
           transfrom = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
           frame.origin.y = 10.0f;
           frame.origin.x = 10.0f;
           frame.size.width = [UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
           frame.size.height = 240.0f;

       break;

       case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
           transfrom = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(90));
           frame.origin.y = 0.0f;
           frame.origin.x = 0.0f;
           frame.size.width =[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
           frame.size.height =[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
       break;

       case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight: 
           transfrom = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(-90));
           frame.origin.y = 0.0f;
           frame.origin.x = 0.0f;
           frame.size.width =[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
           frame.size.height =[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
          break;

       default:
       return;
       break;
   };


   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations: ^{
        self.videoView.frame = frame;
        self.videoView.transform = transfrom;
   }];

}
```

**This code is written without testing and is only here to give you an idea of how it can be doen.**

Comment: have you any idea how to do it?

Comment: When I rotate the device, the view is rotating but on button click how to rotate a view i don't know.

Comment: This would be the cleanest, nicest way to do it but is actually not how Youtube, Facebook or any of these guys are dealing with it. Rotating only the layer would mean the underlying UIViewController is still in portrait mode. Then, showing a system UIAlertView, UIActionSheet or even the keyboard would make them appear in portrait. To have them appear in landscape, the UIViewController should also be in landscape. That's why @sumit-mundra's answer is actually a more valid one, even if hacky...

Comment: Yes that is correct, they have since changed it. Because I know that Facebook did display alert in portrait even though the view was in landscape. Seems that have since fixed this.